# Modifying Sharepoint List From External Web Application REST API

Tags: java, angular, rest, http, sharepoint

I am attempting to modify items in a Sharepoint list using the Sharepoint REST API from back-end java code. I am using NTLM authentication to access the server and Apache httpclient to perform the http requests. I am able to perform a GET request to the list URL without issue, but when doing a POST request, I am receiving an error:

> The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP PATCH
>   method

Here is the relevant code for the POST request:

```
JsonObject type = new JsonObject();
type.addProperty("type", "SP.Data.MyListListItem");
JsonObject listJson2 = new JsonObject();
listJson2.add("__metadata",  type);
listJson2.addProperty("Title", "test");
String backToString = listJson2.toString();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient2 = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost(LIST_URL);
httpPost2.setEntity(new StringEntity(backToString));
httpPost2.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);
httpPost2.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
httpPost2.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
httpPost2.addHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
httpPost2.addHeader("IF_MATCH", "*");

CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpClient2.execute(httpPost2, context);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I am following the post request from https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest.

Comment: What is the `LIST_URL` you are sending your request to as it seems you are sending post to List endpoint, not the items' one.

Comment: My LIST_URL is https://<site name>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items(2)

Comment: Can you add your backToString value that is being sent, also is `MyList` a simple list or library - as then the `type` property should be different.

Comment: MyList is a form library. When I printed out backToString I got {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListListItem"},"Title":"test"} I am unsure if I am using the right type property.

Comment: in that case change your `type.addProperty("type", "SP.Data.MyListListItem");` to `type.addProperty("type", "SP.Data.MyListItem");` and let me know if that helps

Comment: Tried it, got same error message.

Comment: Ok. Let's check the type first, execute `GET` request on your `https://<site name>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items(2)` element and check the `d.__metadata.type` as I don't know if MyList is also the internal name of that list or not. The other thing is that your header `"IF_MATCH"` should be `"IF-MATCH"`. Last thing is that you have an invisible char in your `"test"` (between `s` and `t`)

Comment: The `d.__metadata.type` is `SP.Data.MyListItem`, and even after changing IF_MATCH to IF-MATCH it did not fix the error.